# How does neglecting the mass of a spring with non-negligible mass affect the calculation of the total energy of the oscillator?

Tags: classical-mechanics, energy, harmonic-oscillator, spring, oscillators

Consider a spring-mass system with spring constant $k$ undergoing simple harmonic motion with amplitude $A$. How/why will neglecting the mass contributed to the oscillator by the spring itself affect the calculation of the total energy of the system?

My textbook claims that neglecting the mass of the spring will cause the calculation of the oscillator’s kinetic energy $$T=\frac{1}{2}mv^2=\frac{1}{2}m{\omega}^2A^2\sin^{2}{(\omega t+\delta)}$$ to be too small, which will cause the calculation of the total energy to be too small.

However, isn’t the energy of a simple harmonic oscillator $$E_\text{total}=\frac{1}{2}kA^2$$ independent of the mass of the system? If this is the case, then (so long as the spring constant $k$ and the amplitude $A$ are given and unchanged) I would think that the calculation of the energy of the system would be unaffected by this correction.

This interpretation seems to be consistent with the energy configuration of the system at maximum displacement from equilibrium ($x=A$). In this state, the mechanical energy of the oscillator is entirely potential, so that $U=\frac{1}{2}kx^2$ is equivalent to the total energy $E_\text{total}=\frac{1}{2}kA^2$. Thus, the total energy of the system would seem to be independent of the kinetic energy (and therefore independent of the mass of the system) at this point in time; it would follow that this is so for all configurations of the oscillator.

My thinking is that, since the angular frequency for a spring-mass system in simple harmonic motion is $\omega=\sqrt{k/m}$, the increase in the mass of the system would be offset by the decrease in the angular frequency so that the calculation of the kinetic energy is left unchanged by adjusting for the mass of the spring. Then, the total energy of the oscillator is independent of mass.

Is this reasoning correct?

Comment: Related question and links therein https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/312905/23615

Comment: If the spring is moving and has a mass, then it has a kinetic energy term:  $E_{total} = \frac{1}{2}kx^2 + T$. Also at maximum displacement the velocity of the spring is zero meaning that it has no kinetic energy and the total energy is purely potential like you said.

Comment: Yes you are correct. But your quote from the textbook does not include any context so it is not possible to say whether the textbook is wrong. For example, what is $m$ in your 1st equation? If it is only the mass of the load and neglects the mass of the spring then it underestimates total energy, whereas if it includes the effective mass of the spring then it shows the correct value for total energy.