# Simple Harmonic Motion - spring with mass

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, mass, spring, continuum-mechanics

I'm reading about the following set-up:

> We have a body of mass $m$ attached to a spring. The restoring force is proportional to the displacement of the body from equilibrium. Using Newton's 2nd law we derive the equation of motion being a sine curve.

The author specified however that the spring was massless. How does the spring having a mass affect the situation?

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/64934/2451 , http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/78711/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/312905/2451 and links therein.