# Question about massive spring and SHM

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, mass, harmonic-oscillator, spring

> A mass $M$ is resting on the end of a spring with constant $K$. The mass of the spring is $m$, and the displacement of each element of the spring is proportional to the distance from the fixed end of the spring. Find the total kinetic energy of the spring.

I've never encountered a problem that includes the mass of the spring before, so I really don't know where to start...

Comment: This is a classic problem in introductory courses, I cannot imagine your textbook *not* discussing this in any way.

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/64934/2451 and links therein.