# Energy of Mass Spring System with Mass of Spring Account

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, mass, spring, continuum-mechanics

I am supposed to arrive at the following conclusion for total energy for a spring mass system with mass $M$ spring constant $k$ and spring mass $m$.

$$E = \frac{1}{2}(M + \frac{m}{3})v^2 + \frac{1}{2}kx^2$$

I consider the resting length of the spring $l_o$. An infinitesimal amount of spring will have $\frac{m}{l_0}dl$. I am having troubles relating the velocity of the mass $M$ with the velocity of this small amount of spring.... If I can do this, then the kinetic energy of the spring becomes apparent. Could someone help?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/64934/2451

Answer (score 0):

A diagram would be easier, but assuming the mass M is at one end with a fixed wall on the other end, the spring end touching M will move the same as M, the other end will not move at all, and there should be a linear variation in between. You can integrate.
Most spring-mass systems neglect the spring mass, i.e. M >> m

Comment: Why is there linear variation is my question